# How to declare a managed_file field in schema.yml

Tags: 10

We develop a Drupal 10 module with a complex settings form.
In this form we have an image field based on managed_file.

```
home_image:
  type: managed_file
  title: Image
  description: 'Override the default image of the home page.'
  upload_location: 'public://mymodule/'
  upload_validators:
    file_validate_is_image: []
    file_validate_extensions: ['gif png jpg jpeg']
```

Everything is working well and we can provide an image and use it in controller and template.

We declare the schema.yml file to allow webmasters to translate the settings for each languages. And of course this image has to be translatable too.

I read the [Configuration schema/metadata](https://www.drupal.org/node/1905070) documentation, try to understand the logic in the config_translation module and install the [Configuration Inspector module](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_inspector) to see if everything was right. But until now I'm unable to add a managed_file field on the translation form.

I tried to declare the field as string, as a sequence of string, as an integer (or a sequence of integer). I looked in all the core and contrib extensions I use to see if I can find any example of managed_file field in a schema.yml without success.

I'm quite sure it must be possible, and I even find an issue where a user seems to have managed it ([Default value of managed file field for config translation set to source value even if the translation set for field is empty](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3076789))

However, after days of trying and testing, we cannot manage to make it work.

Eventually, one of our developers propose to add our own type for managed file, but I'm afraid it's a bit a lot to do it in our custom module.

In the mymodule.module :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_config_schema_info_alter().
 */
function mymodule_config_schema_info_alter(&$definitions) {
  foreach ($definitions as $type => &$definition) {
    if ($type === 'managed_file' && !isset($definition['form_element_class'])) {
      $definition['form_element_class'] = '\Drupal\mymodule\FormElement\ManagedFile';
    }
  }
}
```

And in the src/FormElement/ManagedFile.php :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\FormElement;

use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;
use Drupal\config_translation\FormElement\FormElementBase;

/**
 * Defines the managed_file element for the configuration translation interface.
 */
class ManagedFile extends FormElementBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getSourceElement(LanguageInterface $source_language, $source_config) {
    return $this->getTranslationElement($source_language, $source_config, $source_config) + [
      '#default_value' => ['fids' => $source_config],
      '#disabled' => TRUE,
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getTranslationElement(LanguageInterface $translation_language, $source_config, $translation_config) {
    return [
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
    ] + parent::getTranslationElement($translation_language, $source_config, $translation_config);
  }

}
```

Finally, I would like to know if there is a better and simpler way to do so.